# Selecting points based on distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a set of points and would like to filter the points such that I have one point at every 5000m interval. At the moment my points are all approximately 2500m apart.

How can I go about doing this within Global Mapper, QGIS or ArcGIS (Basic Licence)?

[image]

Comment: Please choose one software for your question. You can also ask another question for other softwares.

Answer (score 2):

In ArcGIS use the fishnet tool to create label points with a spacing of 5000m.  Use one of your existing point locations as a fishnet origin coordinate.  Then use select by location to get rid of the fishnet points beyond the extent of your data. 
 Finally, use Spatial Joint to populate these new points with the 2500m points if needed.